# What does the #110 and #112 mean in InstalledProductRegistration attribute for a VSPackage?

Tags: vsix, vspackage

Boilerplate code for a VSPackage adds the InstalledProductRegistration to the package. For product name and product description it uses #110 and #112 for the arguments? What do those mean or map to? I can not find a comprehensively list anywhere.

```
[InstalledProductRegistration("#110", "#112", "1.0", IconResourceID = 400)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The #110 and #112 map to the package's boilerplate Resource file.